# How to do approximate match within If statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a code ;however, it might not work properly. The If statement only works on absolute value. Assuming that someone made an entry for ItemType in lowercase, the If statement would not be able to pick up the value and so the appropriate worksheet would not be updated. I would like to eliminate the possible error or ommitance in the workbook.

```
Sub test()

' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Data
Dim ws0 As Worksheet: Set ws0 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg FG
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg FG")
' ----------------------------------------------------------------- Mfg RAW
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABCX Mfg RAW")


Dim ItemNumber As String
Dim ItemType As String
Dim Issues As String
Dim InventoryValue As String

ItemNumber = InputBox("Please enter Item Number", "Item Number", "Type here")
ItemType = InputBox("Please enter Item Type", "Item Type", "Type here")
Issues = InputBox("Please enter Number of Issues", "Issues", "Type here")
InventoryValue = InputBox("Please enter Inventory Value", "Inventory Value", "Type here")

'-------------------- Data
NextRow = ws0.Cells(ws0.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

 ws0.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = ItemNumber
 ws0.Range("F" & NextRow).Value = ItemType
 ws0.Range("H" & NextRow).Value = Issues
 ws0.Range("I" & NextRow).Value = InventoryValue

 ws0.Range("A" & NextRow - 1 & ":I" & NextRow - 1).Copy
 ws0.Range("A" & NextRow & ":I" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'----------------- If statement
If ItemType = "Mfg FG" Then
ws1.Activate
Range("A13").Activate
 ElseIf ItemType = "Mfg RAW" Then
 ws2.Activate
 Range("A13").Activate

End If

'-------------------- Loop
Do

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Loop

ActiveCell.Value = ItemNumber
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Issues
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = InventoryValue



 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So, without going through the code in detail, what you want is to compare input against other values, but upper and lower case won't match? In that case you can look into using `Option compare text`. Alternatively you can look into `StrComp("abc", "ABC", vbTextCompare)`. Furthermore, I can see lot's of use of `ActiveCell` which in general should be avoided where possible. There are other, better, ways to reference cells.

Comment: Yes, all that activating has to go. You could do `If lcase(ItemType) = "mfg fg"`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your vars to uppercase
UPPER(ItemType)
UPPER(Issues)
UPPER(InventoryValue)

And your comparison values to uppercase eg: UPPER("MFG FG"). Then it wont matter what way they type it in.
Also the previous commenters are speaking the gospel truth about ACTIVECELL. Using that is BEGGING for issues!